# On the representation of conditional expectation by a mesurable function of the conditioning random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X,Y,Z$ be integrable random variables. It is known that $E[X|Y,Z]$ can be written as a measurable function of $Y,Z$ (by the monotone class theorem), i.e, there exists a real measurable function on $\mathbb R^2$, $h_X$, such that $h_X(Y,Z)= E[X|Y,Z]$ almost surely, or $h_X(y,z)= E[X|Y=y,Z=z]$.

Now consider the function $f(X,Y,Z)=X-h_X(Y,Z)$. We see that $f(X,Y,X)=0$.

Is it true that $f(x,Y,x)=0$ almost surely for all $x \in \mathbb R$ ?

The question might seem trivial, but I fear I am missing something when going from random variables to real numbers. I do not think defining $f(X,Y,Z)$ is enough for $f(x,y,z)$ to be well defined for $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$, so I am unsure that I can write something like $f(x,Y,x)$.

Comment: Why is $f(X,Y,X)=0$ ?

Comment: @KurtG. I imagined that $f(X,Y,X) = X - E[X|Y,X]= X-X = 0$, am I wrong?

Comment: You have $f(x, y, z) = x - E(X \mid Y = y, Z = z)$. So $f(X, Y, X)$ is probably not equal to $0$.

Comment: $h_X(Y,X)$ and $\mathbf{E}[X\mid Y,X]$ are in general different random variables. As an extreme case, suppose that $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are independent. Then $$h_X(Y,X)=\mathbf{E}[X],\qquad\text{whereas}\qquad\mathbf{E}[X\mid Y,X]=X.$$

Comment: @W.Volante . The notation $E[X|Z=z]$ leads to much confusion. $E[X|Z=z]$ is a function $f(z)$ such that $E[X|Z]=f(Z)$ ( Doob Dynkin lemma ). We don't have $f(X)=E[X|X]$ ! A counter example is given by Sangchul Lee.

Comment: Thank you both!